# Array error with string

Tags: java, arrays

I have an issue with string array where's the program takes the use names the put it in the screen. I did some coding and creating 2D games and android app but the fact I never used array for saving scores or something and now I'm stuck and need to learn it and code below think of it as we are putting degrees for collage students put the error that  the array is making an error and I can't figure it out why the full code below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Chatlength = new String[10];

    for(i =0; i <= Chatlength.length ; i++){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ss = s.nextLine();
        Chatlength[i] = ss;


        }
    while(true){
    if(i > Chatlength.length){
            int ints = 0;
        while(ints <10){
            System.out.println("Name "+ints+": "+Chatlength[ints]);
            ints++;
        }
    }
    }
```

It gives me and error with `Chatlength[i] = ss;`.

Comment: Well *what* error does it give? You not having enough time isn't a good reason for writing a bad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` due to your loop bounds:

```
for(i =0; i <= Chatlength.length ; i++){
```

That should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Chatlength.length; i++) {
```

... using a local variable declaration instead of the static variable which I assume you've declared in code that you haven't shown us.

An array of length 10 has valid indexes of 0 to 9 inclusive. It's *very* rare that you actually want `<=` for a loop index variable when you're trying to iterate over a collection. (All the standard collections in Java are 0-based, so you pretty much always want to have an exclusive upper bound.)

Additionally, I strongly suggest that you start following Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is culprit. You are going one plus the size of array.

```
i <= Chatlength.length
```

Change it to

```
i < Chatlength.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `for` - loop:

```
for(i =0; i <= Chatlength.length ; i++)
```

should be

```
for(i =0; i < Chatlength.length ; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't declare the array first:

```
 Chatlength = new String[10];  //Wrong code;
```

change it to :

```
 String[] Chatlength = new String[10];
```

then java is zero based and you should use this:

```
 for(i =0; i < Chatlength.length ; i++)
```

Comment: Actually `Chatlength = new String[10];` is fine. It's probably a class member that's `String[]`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such index i=10 for the array you created, as per your condition in loop, it allows i=10 (i<= Chatlength.length) which is not a valid array location hence you got the exception